# Unity 5.5.0b4 - Scroll rect "elastic" mode doesn't work

Tags: uiscrollview, unity-game-engine, scrollrect

i need your help. Look, I've got gameobject and on that gameobject is Unity script called "Scroll Rect". The Content of it is the 'Container', where are buttons. When i set the "Horizontal" value to false and then scroll up the container ( in the game), then the problem appears.

Can you help me please ?

Look at it
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGm9K.png)

Comment: What exactly is your issue here?

Comment: When I set value of Movement type (in Inspektor) to "Elastic", it'll do nothing.

Comment: is the RectTransform size of the ScrollRect.content big enough to contain all 5 buttons ?

Comment: Yep.Content has got Content size fitter script, so it'll automatically set size of it.